# Why does my SVM's performance drop after scaling the training and test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I am using scikit-learn to carry out Sentiment Analysis of text. My features right now are just word frequency counts.

When I do the following, the averaged F-measure is around 59%:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.LinearSVC(class_weight='auto');
clf.fit(Xfeatures, YLabels);
......
predictedLabels = clf.predict(XTestFeatures);
```

But when I use StandardScalar() to scale my feature vector, the averaged F-measure drops to 49%:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.LinearSVC(class_weight='auto');
Xfeatures = scaler.fit_transform(Xfeatures);
clf.fit(Xfeatures, YLabels);
......
XTestFeatures = scaler.transform(XTestFeatures);
predictedLabels = clf.predict(XTestFeatures);
```

Scaling is supposed to improve the performance of my SVM, but here, it seems to decrease the performance. Why does this happen? How can I make it right?

Answer (score 5):

Scaling by mean and variance isn't a good strategy for term frequencies. Suppose you have two term histograms with three terms (let's just call them `0, 1, 2`):

```
>>> X = array([[100, 10, 50], [1, 0, 2]], dtype=np.float64)
```

and you scale them; then you get

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
>>> scale(X)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1.]])
```

The scaling just made it impossible to tell that term 2 occurred more often in `X[1]` than term 0 did. In fact, the fact that term 1 did *not* occur in `X[1]` is no longer distinguishable.

Of course, this is a very extreme example, but similar effects occur in larger sets. What you should do instead is normalize the histograms:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
>>> normalize(X)
array([[ 0.89087081,  0.08908708,  0.4454354 ],
       [ 0.4472136 ,  0.        ,  0.89442719]])
```

This preserves the relative frequencies of the terms, which is what you're interested in; *more* positive terms than negatives ones is what a linear sentiment classifier cares about, not the actual frequency or a scaled variant of it.

(Scaling is recommended for domains where the scale of individual features actually does *not* matter, typically because features are measured in different units.)

Answer (score 3):

Tnere are at least few things to consider:

- scaling data **can** decrease accuracy. It should not, but can
- accuracy is a **wrong measure** for imbalanced problems, you use "class_weight='auto'", so it is your case. Use some balanced measure instead like averaged accuracy or MCC.
- you seem to use **default hyperparameter** of linear SVM, meaning `C=1` and; it might bring **any, nearly random results**, you have to fit the best hyperparameters by some optimziation technique (at least grid search) in order to compare two different data processing (for example your scaling)

Comment: - I am using an averaged F-measure to compare the 2 methods.
- I am using a LinearSVC with its default parameters. I will look into grid search, but can you tell me why the default parameters yields random results?

Comment: `LinearSVC` doesn't use kernels.